# sqlalchemy: max value for each value in another column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to replicate this (postgresql) SQL in sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT MAX(building.id) FROM building JOIN owner ON building.owner_id = owner.id WHERE owner.name IN ('rita', 'sue', 'bob') GROUP BY version.name;
```

This finds one building (the most recent) that's owned by each of the specified owners (NB: data changed to protect the innocent: it makes more sense why I'm doing this in the real context, I promise).

I'm a bit of an sqlalchemy n00b, and I can't figure out how to do this in sqlalchemy. This is what I've currently got:

```
subquery = db.query(func.max(model.Building.id))
subquery = subquery.filter(model.Building.owner.has(model.Owner.name.in_(names)))
subquery = subquery.group_by(model.Owner.name)
print(subquery.all())
```

It reports:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) missing FROM-clause entry for table "owner"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I was missing the equivalent of the join. This code works:

```
subquery = db.query(func.max(model.Building.id))
subquery = subquery.filter(model.Building.owner_id==model.Owner.id)
subquery = subquery.filter(model.Building.owner.has(model.Owner.name.in_(names)))
subquery = subquery.group_by(model.Owner.name)
print(subquery.all())
```

Comment: You could also produce the join exactly as it was, instead of using `EXISTS` and a pre SQL-92 join style: `db.query(...).join(model.Building.owner).filter(model.Owner.name.in_(names)).group_by(model.Owner.name)`